# tf.data multi output model has labels with incompatible shapes

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.data.dataset

I am trying to convert an workbook I did some time ago on Colab (using ImageDataGenerator) to one that uses tf.data.dataset as I now have a multi-gpu set up and am trying to learn how to do faster training. The model trains on the age/ gender/ race dataset from Kaggle but in this instance we're interested in just the sex and age prediction. Sex will either be 0 or 1 and the loss function is binarycrossentropy while age is an integer between 0 and 120 and the loss function is mse at it is regression.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
batch_size = 64

#Load datasets from directories
train_gen = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.listdir(training_dir), shuffle = False)
valid_gen = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(os.listdir(validation_dir), shuffle = False)

def decode_img(img):
    #Convert compressed string into a 3D tensor
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img, tf.float32)
    #Resize the image to the desired size
    return tf.image.resize(img, [128,128])


def get_label(file):
    
    gender = get_sex(file) #returns either 0 or 1
    age = get_age(file)     #returns interger between 0 and about 120
    return gender, age

def process_path(file):
    file = file.numpy()
    file_path = str(bytes.decode(file))
    file = file_path.split(' ')[-1].split("\\")[-1]
    labels = get_label(file)
    # Load data from file as a String
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    img = img / 255.0

    return img, labels


def _set_shapes(t1, t2):
    t1.set_shape((128,128,3))
    t2.set_shape((2,))
        
    return (t1,t2)


train_gen = train_gen.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(process_path, [x], [tf.float32, tf.int32]), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
valid_gen = valid_gen.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(process_path, [x], [tf.float32, tf.int32]), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

train_gen = train_gen.map(_set_shapes,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
valid_gen = valid_gen.map(_set_shapes, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)


train_gen = train_gen.batch(batch_size)
valid_gen = valid_gen.batch(batch_size)

train_gen
```

Output: <BatchDataset shapes: ((None, 128, 128, 3), (None, 2)), types: (tf.float32, tf.int32)>

```
#configure for performance
def config_for_performance(ds):
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
    return ds

train_gen = config_for_performance(train_gen)
valid_gen = config_for_performance(valid_gen)
```

The model itself:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dense, Dropout, Input, Activation, Flatten, BatchNormalization, PReLU
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras import mixed_precision

mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')

gpus = tf.config.list_logical_devices('GPU')
#print(gpus)
strategy = tf.distribute.MirroredStrategy(gpus,cross_device_ops=tf.distribute.ReductionToOneDevice())
with strategy.scope():

    #Define the convolution layers
    inp = Input(shape=(128,128,3))
    cl1 = Conv2D(32,(3,3), padding='same', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(inp)
    bn1 = BatchNormalization()(cl1)
    pr1 = PReLU(alpha_initializer='he_uniform')(bn1)
    cl2 = Conv2D(32,(3,3), padding='same',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(pr1)
    bn2 = BatchNormalization()(cl2)
    pr2 = PReLU(alpha_initializer='he_uniform')(bn2)
    mp1 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(pr2)
    cl3 = Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding='same',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(mp1)
    bn3 = BatchNormalization()(cl3)
    pr3 = PReLU(alpha_initializer='he_uniform')(bn3)
    cl4 = Conv2D(64,(3,3), padding='same',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(pr3)
    bn4 = BatchNormalization()(cl4)
    pr4 = PReLU(alpha_initializer='he_uniform')(bn4)
    mp2 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(pr4)
    cl5 = Conv2D(128,(3,3), padding='same',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(mp2)
    bn5 = BatchNormalization()(cl5)
    pr5 = PReLU(alpha_initializer='he_uniform')(bn5)
    mp3 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(pr5)
    cl6 = Conv2D(256,(3,3), padding='same',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(mp3)
    bn6 = BatchNormalization()(cl6)
    pr6 = PReLU(alpha_initializer='he_uniform')(bn6)
    mp4 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(pr6)
    cl7 = Conv2D(512,(3,3), padding='same',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(mp4)
    bn7 = BatchNormalization()(cl7)
    pr7 = PReLU(alpha_initializer='he_uniform')(bn7)
    mp5 = MaxPool2D((2,2))(pr7)
    flt = Flatten()(mp5)

    #This layer predicts age
    agelayer = Dense(128, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(flt)
    agelayer = BatchNormalization()(agelayer)
    agelayer = Dropout(0.6)(agelayer)
    agelayer = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='age_output', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', dtype='float32')(agelayer)

    #This layer predicts gender
    glayer = Dense(128, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001), kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(flt)
    glayer = BatchNormalization()(glayer)
    glayer = Dropout(0.5)(glayer)
    glayer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='gender_output', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', dtype='float32')(glayer)

    modelA = Model(inputs=inp, outputs=[glayer,agelayer])

    model_folder = 'C:/Users/mm/OneDrive/Documents/Age estimation & gender classification/models'

    if not os.path.exists(model_folder):
        os.mkdir(model_folder)

    #Callback to control learning rate during training. Reduces learning rate by 5% after 3 epochs of no improvement on validation loss
    lr_callback = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.95, patience=3,min_lr=0.000005)

    #Callback to stop training if after 100 epochs of no improvement it stops and restores the best weights
    es_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=100, restore_best_weights=True, min_delta=0.001)

    #Compile Model A
    modelA.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss={'gender_output': BinaryCrossentropy(), 'age_output': 'mse'}, metrics={'gender_output': 'accuracy', 'age_output':'mae'})

#Training Model A
history = modelA.fit(train_gen, epochs=100, validation_data=valid_gen, callbacks=[es_callback,lr_callback])
```

The error message:

INFO:tensorflow:Using MirroredStrategy with devices ('/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0', '/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1')
Epoch 1/100
INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py", line 130, in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
labels.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(logits.get_shape())
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 1161, in assert_is_compatible_with
raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))
ValueError: Shapes (None, 2) and (None, 1) are incompatible

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\coordinator.py", line 297, in stop_on_exception
yield
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\mirrored_run.py", line 346, in run
self.main_result = self.main_fn(*self.main_args, **self.main_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 692, in wrapper
return converted_call(f, args, kwargs, options=options)
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 382, in converted_call
return _call_unconverted(f, args, kwargs, options)
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 463, in _call_unconverted
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 835, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
show more (open the raw output data in a text editor) ...

File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py", line 206, in wrapper
return target(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\mm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_impl.py", line 132, in sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits
raise ValueError("logits and labels must have the same shape (%s vs %s)" %
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 1) vs (None, 2))

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Managed to resove this with a bit of research and trial and error. Main issues are:

1. The labels are being fed to the model as a tuple instead of being separated. When it is multiple output heads this is necessary:

```
def process_path(file):
    file = file.numpy()
    file_path = str(bytes.decode(file))
    file = file_path.split("\\")[-1]
    gender, age = get_label(file)
    # Load data from file as a String
    img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    img = decode_img(img)
    img = img / 255.0

    return img, gender, age
```

NB: I made a modification to extracting the labels from the filename as it wasn't getting it right all the time:

```
file = file_path.split("\\")[-1]
```

2. Due to the change on 1, the map functions need an additional dtype for the other label, so it becomes:

```
train_gen = train_gen.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(process_path, [x], [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32]), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
valid_gen = valid_gen.map(lambda x: tf.py_function(process_path, [x], [tf.float32, tf.int32, tf.int32]), num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

3. Each label needs to be reshaped:

```
def _set_shapes(t1, t2, t3):
    t1.set_shape((128,128,3))
    t2.set_shape((1,))
    t3.set_shape((1,))
    t2 = tf.reshape(t2, [-1,1])
    t3 = tf.reshape(t3, [-1,1])
    return (t1,t2,t3)
```